# compare file security settings between two files in Windows using cmd

Tags: windows, file, cmd, compare

similar to:

fc file1 file2

but I need results displayed of file properties or file security settings.

Answer (score 2):

Playing just a bit I could manage to do for files A and B:

```
icacls A > A_file.txt
icacls B > B_file.txt
```

And compare the command results with:

```
fc A_file.txt B_file.txt
```

Maybe you need to do some processing to the original ICACLS output, or use a different tool than FC.

Answer (score 1):

thanks @hernan i was able to accomplish what i needed with following

Echo Y| cacls filename1.ext

then

Echo Y| cacls filename2.ext

and compare on screen.